# Pug iteration: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: express, pug

I am having the following data in js file:

```
let data =[
  {id:1,type:"action"},
  {id:2,type:"comedy"}
];
```

and trying to print it using pug template

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/style.css')
  body

        table
          tr
            th Id
            th Type
          each post in data
            tr
              td #{post.id}
              td #{post.type}
  block content
```

I get the error as "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" at the each post line

app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
let data =[
  {id:1,type:"action"},
  {id:2,type:"comedy"}
];

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Movies' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: please provide your ExpressJs codes

Comment: added pls advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`index.js:`

```
let data =[
  {id:1,type:"action"},
  {id:2,type:"comedy"}
];

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Movies', data }); // you forgot passing the data array
})
```

Another solution is:

In the `app.js`, you could do this:

```
var app = express();
let data =[
  {id:1,type:"action"},
  {id:2,type:"comedy"}
];
app.locals.data = data; //added
```

Now you can access local variables in templates rendered within the application which mean you don't need to pass this `data` in the `render()` method

Comment: try to move your `data` to `index.js` file

Comment: It works if I move it to index.js.But how can I access it from app.js?

Comment: Export it then include in the file? Those are js basics.

Comment: Or if i have to access data from json file?

Comment: @MohammedAjmal in `app.js` you could set `app.locals.data = data` and get it in the `index.js`. For more infomation, see this: [Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app)

Comment: @MohammedAjmal In addition, after setting the `app.locals.data = data`, you can access this `data` in templates rendered without passing it in `render()` method.