# Trying to iterate over JSON in Pug but keep getting length error

Tags: node.js, json, express, command-line-interface, pug

I am using express and pug.

here is the index.js file :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var bookStore = [
        {
            title: "Templating with Pug",
            author: "Winston Smith",
            pages: 143,
            year: 2017
        },
        {
            title: "Node.js will help",
            author: "Guy Fake",
            pages: 879,
            year: 2015
        }
    ];
    res.render("index", {
        bookStore: bookStore
    });
});
```

here is the pug template :

```
each book in bookStore
    ul
        li= book.title
        li= book.author
        li= book.pages
        li= book.year
```

everytime I try to use the pug cli to translate the index.pug file, I get this error:

```
TypeError: index.pug:1
  > 1| each book in bookStore
    2|     ul
    3|         li= book.title
    4|         li= book.author

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug-cli\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:6:32)
    at eval (eval at wrap (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug-cli\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:53:4)
    at template (eval at wrap (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug-cli\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:54:3)
    at renderFile (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug-cli\index.js:285:40)
    at C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug-cli\index.js:149:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pug-cli\index.js:148:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32) {
  path: 'index.pug'
}
```

At first I wasn't confident about my code. But this is a supposedly working example :
https://pug.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/9545/iteration-with-pug

What am I doing wrong, it seems that since pug cli dosn't "know" the bookStore variable it won't compile... But isn't that the principle of templating ?
Did I miss some declaration or something ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pug iteration: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606235/pug-iteration-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Comment: No it won't because for me it's when I try to compile de pug file with CLI :s I al already passing the array bookStore as you can see on my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use express to do that which [Getting started with pug](https://pug.programmingpedia.net/) mentioned it instead of cli.

First, run `npm install express pug` to install package.

Second, setup your server.js with following code.

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

// setup template you want to use.
app.set("view engine", "pug")

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {test: [1,2,3]})
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Third, setup your index.pug into "views/index.pug" with following content.

```js
div
    each val in test
        ul
            li= val
```

Now your folder structure will look like this.

```
|-- node_modules
|-- server.js
|-- views
|----|---index.pug
```

Fourth, start your server by `node server.js`.

Final, type `http://localhost:8080` url in browser, you'll see the result.

Comment: Oh well ! I am going too fast... Thanks Yu, it works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Well I got figured it out : when you are compiling the .pug file, with an array, you must use the -O option to specify some variables :
`pug -O '{"bookStore": "test"}' index.pug`
works, but :
`pug  index.pug` don't work.

That's a bit weird I think.

Comment: But, if you use express with pug, you don't need to setup extra compiler option to do that.